# Как применить групповую политику от домена

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-server, group-policy

Есть сервер, в нём настроил GPMC для определённых доменных пользователей. На сервере политика применяется, но на других ПК уже нет (домену они подключены).
Хочу узнать: нужно настроить ПК или же этого делать не надо и я не правильно настроил групповую политику.

Comment: Скрин вкладки `Делегирование` в студию.

Comment: https://ibb.co/WWHfkLF - ссылка на скрин

Comment: `Компьютеры домена` не вижу. Добавь.

Comment: Хардкорить юзеров для gpo - такое себе. Лучше объедини их в группу и назначай уже на неё.

Answer (score 1):

Групповые политики компьютера и пользователя по умолчанию обновляются каждые 90 минут в фоновом режиме. Также они обновляются каждый раз при запуске системы.

Если Вы хотите немедленно обновить групповые политики не перегружая компьютер, запустите консоль от имени Администратора. И введите команду:

```
gpupdate /force
```

Comment: Я знаю об этом. Вручную применял групповую политику, но как будто компьютеры не спрашивают у сервера о "внешних" изменениях групповой политики.